# C++ Noobie - I cannot get past solving this for my homework assignment. I am stuck. Please help!

Tags: c++

"I cannot seem to get this C++ program to work!! I have been trying for a couple of hours, and I am not grasping the concept. Here is the question from the book:

"Write a C++ function:

```
void rect (int& ar, int& per, int len, int wid)
```

that computes the area ar and perimeter per of a rectangle with length len and width wid. Test it with a main program that inputs the length and width of a rectangle and outputs its area and perimeter. Output the value in the main program, not in the procedure.

This is what is on the instructors instructions:

**#13 from text, pg 83: This program requires you to use a function that accepts the length and width of your rectangle from `main()`, calculates the area and perimeter and returns those values in variables `ar` and `per`. Your `main()` then displays these values. Variables `ar` and `per` must be declared in `main()` and then passed by reference to method `rect()`.

Here is the code that I have written so far. I am stuck on passing the variable by reference to the method rect():

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void rect(int& ar, int& per, int len, int wid)
{
   ar = len * wid;
   cout << "Area: " << ar << ".";
}

int main ()
{
   int ar, per, len, wid;
   cout << "Please enter the length of the rectangle: ";
   cin >> len;
   cout << "Please enter the width of the rectangle: ";
   cin >> wid;

   return 0;
}
```

I know that the calculation is ok in the rect() method because it is compiling correctly. What I cannot figure out is how to call the rect() method from main. Every time I try something, it give me an 'too few arguments to function `'void rect(int&, int&, int, int)' error.`

I am using JGrasp on OS X as my IDE.

Please help!!"

Comment: How are you calling your rect() function?

Comment: +1 for being honest about this being a homework, and for trying to solve it yourself first.

Comment: See, in Java you wouldn't have this problem :) Everything is by value (even references ^-^)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple call with `rect (ar, per, len, wid);` should work fine. You have to provide the right number of parameters as expected by the function (which is four).

And you should probably also add:

```
per = 2 * (len + wid);
```

to your `rect` function as well, but I assume that was coming once you'd sorted this problem out.

You should also move your `cout` statements (both the one you have and the one you will add for perimeter) into `main` since that is what the instructions request.

Other than those niggles, good job!

Answer (score 2):

It should work with

```
rect(ar, per, len, width);
```

What have you tried?

Comment: I have tried `rect(ar);` in the line right above `return 0;`, but I get an error. I think that I just don't know how to properly call the `react()` method.

Comment: @©hris: You need to pass to your function all the parameters that it needs to compute your area!

Comment: @chrisdoto:  `rect` is declared as having four parameters.  You must pass it four arguments:  one for each parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Call it like this:

```
rect (ar, per, len, wid);
```

Comment: Max E. Thanks!!! I feel like an idiot. I knew I was missing something easy. Thanks again!!!

Answer (score 0):

You must declare ar and per before calling function rect in the main.

'&' tells the function not to copy the variable, use this instead.

Hope this helps

Comment: `ar` and `per` _are_ defined in `main`, and OP is _using_ `&` so I'm not sure this is a _great_ help :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo: Yes `ar` and `per` are defined in `main`. Using `&` in function means that you are passing the variable reference, not the value. So you must declare `ar` and `per` before calling the function `rect`.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to pass all of the parameters from the `rect()` method to the `main()` method:

`rect (ar, per, len, wid);`

Thanks for all of the help!! This place is a huge resource.

Comment: I'm sorry that someone downvoted you for this before explaining first. Answer sections should really be left for _answers,_ this is more of a comment that you could have left on your question.

Answer (score 0):

try this...
since you are using rect(int& ar, int& per, ...) no need to pass the reference, it already is.
have a look at this http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=229822

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void rect(int& ar, int& per, int len, int wid)
{
   ar = len * wid;
   per = 2 * (len + wid);
}

int main()
{
   int ar, per, len, wid;
   cout << "Please enter the length of the rectangle: ";
   cin >> len;
   cout << "Please enter the width of the rectangle: ";
   cin >> wid;       

   rect(ar, per, len, wid);    

   cout << "Area: " << ar << ".";
   cout << "Perimeter: " << per << ".";
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: No, seriously, _don't_ use this. Take the hints others have given and apply them to your own code. Otherwise, the instant your educator searches the web for your code, this link will appear and you will have to explain plagiarism. That's one reason why full-code solutions to homework is frowned upon here.

Comment: 100% agree with @paxdiablo - there's another very important reason: If this is homework, then you're probably planning to do this for a living someday, and trust me, you don't want to be the guy who always gets the easy tasks because he doesn't really understand the hard ones. It might seem cliché, but exercises really will make you better at your job in a couple years.

Comment: oops... sorry... i thought i was just helping... but, thank you... there will be no more instant codes from me..